# why error only in 4.3 but works for 5.x/6.x IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat 4.3

Tags: android

I found following SO questions on the same topic

[You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

My question is more about why it only happened on device with Android 4.3. Same code works with Android 5/6

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

v21/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    </style>
</resources>
```

Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is in your code. styles.xml is used on devices with Android 4.3, and v21/styles.xml on device with Android 5+
Try to remove v21/styles.xml and see what happen on Android 5+.

Comment: My bad. So you apply SplashTheme to MyActivity and this activity doesn't start on Android 4.3, am I right?

Comment: Thank you so much sir...my mistake..should have known better